# Bootstrap-multiselect is very slow with a large pool of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

In my application, I'm asking the customer to fill a short form, where one of the fields asks them to select 3 of their favorite cities (or cities which they've visited).

My list of cities to choose from is quite large (3K cities), and I've selected to use bootstrap-multiselect with search. However bootstrap-multiselect is fairly slow with so many options.

My biggest complain is the page load time. Below is a demo with 30 options, wait until it loads, and then run it, you'll see it's super fast.

http://www.bootply.com/07KLihND2q

Now, the demo below has 3K options, wait until it loads and run it. It'll take the multi-select at least 3 seconds to take the desired form!

http://www.bootply.com/wK8zFCjB2D

Is there a way to speed things up and/or replace the bootstap-multiselect by another component which will meet my needs?

I'm looking for something which will allow the users to quickly find their favorite cities (e.g. by text search), will be compact (can be fit into a form as opposed to opening a new window) and will restrict the user to one of the 3K options I have. Being able to populate the element from JSON using js-populate is a big bonus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem, but really wanted to keep the component as it is so convenient.

Our solution was render the component with no options, then use setTimeout to load the options **AFTER the page has rendered**. This stopped the options rendering from holding up the whole page.

It isn't actually any faster, but to the user it seems faster. They can start reading the page and figure out what's going on while you render the options in the background.

Comment: Thanks! I've just independently implemented this solution. I'm running the styling "async"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that component is not well-suited for such a large list of options nor is it the best UX. You'd be better off using something like Typeahead https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Thanks! Typeheads look beautiful, but I see no option to do "multi-select" with them. Am I missing something?

Comment: you could manually append each selection to an object or array on selection in typeahead

Comment: Ok, but for the frontend, it looks like I need to complicate things. I need to say "add city", then dynamically add the typehead if the customer wants to add a city.

Otherwise, my frontend will have 3-5 "city" typeheads, and if the customer wants to use one, the other will be left empty.

Comment: Big thanks, BTW, typeheads slipped my mind, and when I'll have a chance to re-implement things properly, I'll give them a shot

Answer (score 0):

Although obviously not an option for everyone, we were running into the same thing and opted to get rid of Bootstrap's solution in favor of [React Virtualized Select](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select).  It handles huge lists beautifully.